# Return the right having request

Tags: mysql, sql

Can you help with the request? Might be it is duplicated, I understand but I need your help to solve this issue.

My schema:

[image]

I have these very tables:

```
doctors
id name             profession 
 1 James Harden     dental 
 2 James Jones      therapist 
 3 LeBron James     cardiologist 
 4 Kobe Braynt      surgeon 
 5 Sabrina Williams nurse 
 6 Tyler Okonma     speech therapist 
 7 John Snow        pediatrician

patients 
id name         diagnostic 
 1 Mo Bamba     tooth pulling out
 2 Kaney West   astma 
 3 Post Malone  heart attack 
 4 Denzel Curry headache 
 5 Nicola Jokic stomac-ache 
 6 Dwayne Wade  AIDS 
 7 Boo Aby      headahce

visits
doctorId  patientId  visitDate
1           1         2019-03-09
2           4         2019-03-01
2           5         2019-02-26
2           6         2019-02-05
3           3         2019-02-13
4           2         2019-03-07
7           1         2019-02-14
7           7         2019-02-15
```

**I need to print the doctors serving the *largest number* of patients for the previous month.**

My request is:

```
select doctorid, count(distinct patientid) as counter
from visits v
where visitdate >= (curdate() - interval day(visitdate) - 1 day) - interval 1 month and
      visitdate < curdate() - interval day(visitdate) - 1 day
group by doctorid
having count(distinct patientid) = (select count(distinct v2.patientid) as cnt
                                    from visits v2
                                    where v2.visitdate >= ((curdate() - interval day(v2.visitdate) - 1 day) - interval 1 month) and
                                          v2.visitdate < (curdate() - interval day(v2.visitdate) - 1 day)
                                    group by v2.doctorid
                                     order by cnt desc
                                     limit 1
                                   );
```

results from my request:

```
   doctorId   counter
   7              2
```

I do not understand, why it returns only one doctorId.

I need to output only like this:

```
       doctorId   counter
        7           2
        3           2
```

Thanks in avadance.

Comment: The [windowing version](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=104) of this query should return both results

Comment: It happens because of your subquery. It always returns 2 based on your date calculation so you only get one row. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51056d/7

Answer (score 0):

if you have an older Version you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT doctorid, SUM(1) as counter
FROM visits v
WHERE visitdate 
    BETWEEN 
        LAST_DAY(now() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) + interval 1 DAY 
    AND
        LAST_DAY(now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY doctorId
HAVING counter = (
    SELECT count(*) as cnt
    FROM visits
    WHERE visitdate 
        BETWEEN 
            LAST_DAY(now() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) + interval 1 DAY 
        AND
            LAST_DAY(now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    GROUP BY doctorId
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
    LIMIT 1
) ;
```